# Can´t connect to ubuntu 18.04 on Azure after latest updates

Tags: azure

After running apt upgrade on my Ubuntu 18.04 on Azure I can´t connect using SSH, it says Connection closed by remote host.
Trying to login using the Seriel console in Azure does not work either, it just keeps asking for the username.

I installed a new server from scratch in Azure, and also this server can´t be connected to. Any one else having issues recently?

Comment: You can try to reset the password of the VM.

Comment: Tried this, but has not effect. It never gets to input password.

Comment: Do you just run the apt-get upgrade inside the Ubuntu VM? nothing else?

Comment: Yes I had 3 VM that I ran apt upgrade and the restared, after that the SSH login stoped working and some other services like webmin.
I then tried to install a new VM, and it behaves the same way strait away. Tried login in from different networks and different computers. VM that has not been updated work fine

Comment: Two steps, check if the extension OmsAgentForLinux is in success and create a new user for the VM. And also check the NSG rules.

Comment: I have found tha package cousing this:
aadlogin 
updated from 1.0.006350001 to 1.0.008300001
It gives the following error when booting in the console:
[FAILED] Failed to start Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking).

Answer (score 1):

I have now solved the issue by running the command in the Azure portal:

> apt install -y --allow-downgrades aadlogin=1.0.006350001

After reboot the server runs normal, I have reported the issue to Microsoft